# JavaScript - How do I open a new page and pass JSON data to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a page called search.jsp. When the user selects a record and the presses an edit button, I would like to open a new page (in the same window) with the record data (that is stored in a json object and passed to the new page). How do I use Javascript (or jQuery) to open a new page and pass the JSON data?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the replies. The pages are on the same domain. I apologize for not including that in the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two pages are on the same domain, a third way is to use HTML5 localStorage: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

In fact localStorage is precisely intended for what you want. Dealing with GET params or window/document JS references is not very portable (even if, I know, all browsers do not support localStorage).

Comment: I thought local storage was limited by domain somehow (though I don't remember the details)?  After all, you wouldn't want malicious.website.com accessing the localStorage that was set by your.bank.com right?

Comment: You're totally right. The question was asked in a way I thought the two pages would be on the same domain. Edited the answer with the precision. And I found the other solutions a bit ugly..

Comment: Yes; both pages are on the same domain so this will work well. I just have to be careful to clear storage after use.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some very simple pure JavaScript (no HTML, no jQuery) that converts an object to JSON and submits it to another page:

```
/*
    submit JSON as 'post' to a new page
    Parameters:
    path        (URL)   path to the new page
    data        (obj)   object to be converted to JSON and passed
    postName    (str)   name of the POST parameter to send the JSON
*/
function submitJSON( path, data, postName ) {
    // convert data to JSON
    var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(data);

    // create the form
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    form.setAttribute('action', path);

    // create hidden input containing JSON and add to form
    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", postName);
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", dataJSON);
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);

    // add form to body and submit
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Use some PHP like this on the target page to get the JSON:

```
$postVarsJSON = $_POST['myPostName'];
$postVars = json_decode( $postVarsJSON );
```

Or, more simply for JavaScript:

```
var postVars = JSON.parse( <?php $_POST['myPostName']; ?> );
```

Comment: I would like to add an option with a new page. So you can open a new page and submit data if add this: `form.setAttribute('target', '_blank');`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the two pages are on the same domain, you can use the returned object created by window.open() to access (and edit) the window object of a newly opened window.

Comment: I have to keep the new page in the same window (i.e. window.open('edit.jsp', '_self')) How can I manipulate the edit page's window object from the search page when the search page no longer exists?

Comment: can you provide snippet of code which can describe more your answer

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, for example, you have object

```
var dataObject = {
    param  : 'param',
    param2 : 'param2'
};
```

You can translate it into string, using JSON.stringify method

```
var dataObjectString = JSON.stringify(dataObject);
```

Then you should use Base64 encoding to encode you data (base64 encode/decode methods can be easely found in search engines)

```
var dataObjectBase64 = base64encode(dataObjectString);
```

You will get something like this

```
e3BhcmFtIDogJ3BhcmFtJyxwYXJhbTIgOiAncGFyYW0yJ307
```

Then you can pass this string as a parameter:

```
iframe src="http://page.com/?data=e3BhcmFtIDogJ3BhcmFtJyxwYXJhbTIgOiAncGFyYW0yJ307"
```

Finally, reverse actions on the loaded page.

Answer (score 2):

You can create "on the fly" a form with a hidden/text input value this will hold the json value, then you can submit this form via javascript.

Something like this...

**Im using JQUERY AND UNDERSCORE(for template purpose)**

this is the template

```
<form method='<%= method %>' action="<%= action %>" name="<%= name %>" id="<%= id %>" target="_blank">
    <input type='hidden' name='json' id='<%= valueId %>' />
</form>
```

you can then post use it on javascript

```
function makePost(){
    var _t = _.template("use the template here");              
    var o = {
            method : "POST",
            action :"someurl.php",
            name : "_virtual_form",
            id : "_virtual_form_id",
            valueId : "_virtual_value"
        }

    var form = _t(o); //cast the object on the template
            //you can append the form into a element or do it in memory                   
    $(".warp").append(form);        

            //stringify you json        
        $("#_virtual_value").val(JSON.stringify(json)); 
        $("#_virtual_form_id").submit();
        $("#_virtual_form_id").remove();                        
}
```

now you dont have to be worry about the lenght of you json or how many variables to send.

best!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe the local storage solution (proposed by Ulflander) might be a bit simpler since both pages are on the same domain.

Comment: Well this is a crossbrowser solution while Ulflander not, but you right his answer is much simpler cause is just taking advantage of the new features in html5. And of course as you say this solution can help you when your pages are in different domains. best ...

Answer (score 1):

If the the JSON is small enough you can just include it as a GET parameter to the URL when you open the new window.

Something like:

```
window.open(yourUrl + '?json=' + serializedJson)
```

Comment: But I like Jack's answer better; no JSON length limits and no giant mess of JSON in the URL that the user can see.

Comment: I have recently run into this statement, "if JSON is small enough"
How Small is small enough and what are the boundaries involved?

Answer (score 0):

Assume if your json data
**var data={"name":"abc"};**

The page which sends JSON data should have the following code in the script tag.

```
                $.getJSON( "myData.json", function( obj ) {
                console.log(obj);
                for(var j=0;j

<obj.length;j++){
                tData[j]=obj;
                //Passing JSON data in URL
                tData[j]=JSON.stringify(tData[j]);
                strTData[j]=encodeURIComponent(tData[j]);
                //End of Passing JSON data in URL
                tr = $('\


    <tr/>
                    ');
                    //Send the json data as url parameter
                    tr.append("


    <td>" + "

        <a href=\"fetchJSON.html?jsonDATA="+strTData[j]+"\" target=\"_blank\">" +Click here+ "</a>" + "

    </td>
                    ");                 
                    }
                    });
```

The page which receives the JSON data should have the code.

```
<html>
                    <head></head>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
                    <body>
                        <p id="id"></p>
                    </body>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                            function getQuery() {
                                          var s=window.location.search;
                                          var reg = /([^?&=]*)=([^&]*)/g;
                                          var q = {};
                                          var i = null;
                                          while(i=reg.exec(s)) {
                                            q[i[1]] = decodeURIComponent(i[2]);
                                          }
                                          return q;
                            }
                                        var q = getQuery();
                                        try {
                                          var data = JSON.parse(q.jsonDATA);
                                          var name=data.name;
                                          console.log(name);
                                        document.getElementById("id").innerHTML=name;
                                        } catch (err) {
                                          alert(err + "\nJSON=" + q.team);
                                        }

                            </script>
                </html>
```